# how many days did it take for the bacteria to cover one quarter of the petri dish?

Tags: contest-math, education

Bacteria are grown in a petri dish. The amount of bacteria doubles in size every 2 days. If it took 16 days for the bacteria to cover the whole petri dish, how many days did it take for the bacteria to cover one quarter of the petri dish?

Let's solve this two ways.

First if it doubles each day, then that means that if we step backwards in time it halves each day. If on day 16 it was twice as much as day 15, then on day 15 it was half as much as day 16. Similarly day 14 was half a much as day 15 and so forth. So if day 16 was 100% covered, then day 15 was half of 100% covered, or 50% and day 14 was half as much as day 15, so 25% or one quarter. This is probably the expected way to solve it.

I have doubts about my answer and your help would be very helpful.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @MamadyKonaté Welcome to Math SE. Your basic solution method is correct. However, your problem states that "The amount of bacteria doubles in size every 2 days". Then your solution initially states "First if it doubles each day, ...". This contradicts the earlier statement. Using the problem statement instead, the bacteria would cover one quarter of the petri dish in $16 - 2(2) = 12$ days instead of the $16 - 2(1) = 14$ days that you got.

Comment: Since every 2 days the area halves (going backwards), then 8 cycles of 2 days each would reduce the area to $\frac 1{2^8}$. Therefore, starting at $\frac 1{256}$ initial coverage, the coverage will become $\frac 14$ in 6 cycles x 2 days each.

Comment: "Let's solve this two ways." What's the second way?

Comment: Thanks to all for your supports !!!